# How do you go up a level in directory in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to complete laracast course, but running into the error. After running this cod

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', function ($slug){
    $path = __DIR__."/../resources/posts/{$slug}.html";

    ddd($path);

    if (! file_exists($path)){
        return redirect('/');
    }
    $post = file_get_contents($path);
    return view('post', [
        'post' => $post]);
})->where('post', '[A-z_\-]+');
```

I suppose to see the first-post.html, but ddd window opens up saying
"Content: "D:\Projects\laravel\blog\routes/../resources/posts/first-post.html""
Meaning it didn't count "/../" as a "go up a dir", but just read it as folder name.
I double checked the dir blog/resources/posts/first-post.html does exist.

Comment: Where did you learn this? :\

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$path = resource_path('views/posts/'. $slug .'.html');
```

---

You may create a [view](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views) by placing a file with the `.blade.php` extension in your application's `resources/views` directory, **NOT `.html`**.

> The `.blade.php` extension informs the framework that the file contains a [Blade template](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade).

You need to rename `first-post.html` to `first-post.blade.php`.

Once you have created a view, you may return it from one of your application's routes or controllers using the global view helper, and **no need `file_get_contents`**.

```
return view('first-post', $data);
```

As you can see, the first argument passed to the view helper corresponds to the name of the view file in the `resources/views` directory. The second argument is an array of data that should be made available to the view.

Referring to your route; If you want to check if the file exists or not, you can use:

```
$exists = view()->exists('first-post'); // return boolean
```

So, the final code you can use :

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', function ($slug) {
    if (view()->exists($slug)) {
        return view($slug);
    }

    return abort(404); // Show 404 page if view doesn't exists
});
```

---

**Final note**

At the very least, you should check out [the official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs) for an introduction.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Funny thing, its exact code they show you on the official Laravel guide course you can find on laravel website